# From for loop to while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to transform it to while loop.

```
def function(n, step):
    s = 0
    for i in range(1, n, step):
        s += i
    return s
```

Any ideas?

```
def function(n, step):
    s = 0
    i = 1
    while i<n:
```

so i don't know what to do after this.

edit: so the solution is

```
def function(n, step):
s = 0
i = 1
while(i<n):
    s += i
    i += step 
return s
```

Comment: I know you can do it, just give it a try! think, what are the two things that get incremented every iteration of the for-loop? now increase them inside the `while` as well!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do exactly that's present in for loop with 1 additional statement to increment the value of `i` in the body of `while` loop

```
def funt(n, step):
    s = 0
    i = 1
    while i < n:
        s+=i
        i+=1
    return s
```

Comment: @Kaana For most data types, `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y`

Answer (score 0):

`range(a, b, c)` returns you an iterable that starts at `a` and its every step is incremented by `c` until reaching `b`, excluded. So what you are loking for would look like this:

```
def function(n, step):
    s = 0
    i = 1
    while i < n:
        s += i
        i += step
    return s
```

Though, it's not really the way you should do it, unless it's part of python exercise. Nicer way would be:

```
def function(n, step):
    return sum(range(1, n, step))
```

`sum()` is one of Python's in-built functions

Answer (score 0):

You should take the initial value as `1` and increment this value by step in each loop

```
def function(n, step):
    s = 0
    i = 1
    while(i<n):
        s += i
        i += step 
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answers here are correct except they are setting the index at 1. The range() function is 0-index based so i should start with 0. You can check the difference with the following sample code:

```
n = 40
step = 3

def function(n, step):
    s = 0
    for i in range(s, n, step):
        s += i
    return s

def function2(n, step):
    s = 0
    i = 0
    while(i < n):
        s += i
        i += step
    return s

def function3(n, step):
    s = 0
    i = 1
    while(i < n):
        s += i
        i += step
    return s

print("Range function: %s" % function(n, step))
print("While loop, i=0: %s" % function2(n, step))
print("While loop i=1: %s" % function3(n, step))
```

Here's the output from those values

```
Range function: 273
While loop, i=0: 273
While loop i=1: 247
```

Comment: This documentation probably explains it better than I could:

https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/

Specifically this section:

range() (and Python in general) is 0-index based, meaning list indexes start at 0, not 1. eg. The syntax to access the first element of a list is mylist[0]. Therefore the last integer generated by range() is up to, but not including, stop. For example range(0, 5) generates integers from 0 up to, but not including, 5.